# htaccess redirect raw image viewing

Tags: image, .htaccess, redirect

I'd like to redirect any image that is viewed directly to a handler page:

if http:// mysite.com/pics/filename.jpg (or www.)is in the URL
then redirect to http:// mysite.com/pics/index.php?img=filename.jpg (no www)

But if the image is being called by a webpage or a mobile html5 app anywhere then it should be served per normal.

So if mypage.html contains an img tag with the direct photo in it it will be shown in that page. But if http:// mysite.com/pics/filename.jpg is the url then it should redirect. In other words if the file is being viewed directly it should redirect to the wrapper page, but if it's already in a wrapper page (anywhere) it shouldn't redirect.

I've seen various redirect code but none that that references the visible url for the if statement, so I don't know how to do this. And the ones I've found and tried don't work, either redirecting all requests, or not doing anything

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will take care of people hotlinking to images on your site for you:-

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?mysite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ([^/]+)\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ pics/index.php?img=$1.$2 [NC,L,R]
```

As for your mobile HTML5 app you are going to need some other way to identify it to your web server. So you are going to have to see what referer that says it is when it is asking for images. It should be pretty easy for you to write a PHP script to tell you that, then you just need to add to the above code to include that.

Simon

Comment: Hi Simon, I think that does the opposite of what I asked. When someone clicks on a link that is straight to the jpg file I want it to redirect to the php file with ?img=filename.jpg so I can wrap it. And the App and website will be embedding the jpg in an html page so the images will already be wrapped.

Comment: @K'shin so to get this straight you want to redirect the user not rewrite the link?

Comment: Correct, the link in the address bar doesn't matter to me, when someone clicks on an image url directly I'd like it to redirect them to a php page that wraps the image so they get it 'pretty' not just the jpg in the corner of their browser.

Comment: @K'shin I have added the R flag to the rule and it should do what you ask now.

Comment: I've put the code in the .htaccess file of the root directory only changing "mysite" to my site. Unfortunately when I go to a jpg in the pics directory it doesn't appear to do anything, I just see the jpg in the corner of the browser.

Comment: It does, however prevent my app from using the jpg. So it appears to do the exact opposite of what I need.

My app should be able to see the jpg, but no one should be able to go to my site and view the raw jpg, it needs to be wrapped by the index.php.